# How do I reference a Prefab with a script that doesn't implement MonoBehaviour before runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As per the title, I'm essentially looking for a way to associate a Prefab with a script that doesn't implement MonoBehaviour. From the Unity editor, I can normally drag a Prefab and drop it directly into the script, but as soon as I remove MonoBehaviour, I no longer have the option to. I need to remove MonoBehaviour because I'm creating instances of the class that I can pass onto a "manager".

I've seen plenty of examples of people referencing a Prefab through a script through code at runtime, but that seems unnecessary since I'm never going to change the prefab I'm associating with that particular variable, and I have the prefab object ready before any code is actually run. I'm leaning towards Resources.Load() as my answer, but I'm not exactly sure whether that's the ideal thing to do.

Is there any trick to specifying a Prefab before runtime, or what's the most efficient way to associate a GameObject variable with a Prefab in a way similar to the "drag and drop" method of association in the Unity Editor?

Comment: In my search I've come across a post [here](http://prof.johnpile.com/2014/07/20/globalprefabs/)which suggests building a list of global Prefabs prior to running any game code. Since this essentially removes the hassle of loading any Prefabs during _playable_ game time, it will work for me, but I'm still interested to see whether or not it's possible to do the referencing in a way that involves associating the Prefab before runtime altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your normal `C#` class point to a GameObject or a prefab.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NotMonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject gObject;

    public NotMonoBehaviour()
    {
        gObject = Resources.Load("MyPrefab") as GameObject;
    }
}
```

In this case the code goes into the `Resources` folder and finds the Prefab.

[image]

Comment: This will definitely work, I opted to create a prefab manager, but for those that need only a few prefabs in a non-mono class, this is definitely the best solution.